# Wrong behavior with AngularJS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Kindly excuse my English.

I need some help to finish this task:

*php extracts information from the database and reads in JavaScript using JSON and the dynamic show angularjs table.*

Everything is working, but I'm not sure how to do the following:

> On click of 'see', I want the corresponding video to play.

I have tried a lot and haven't been able to achieve what I set for. 
I would appreciate some help as I'm still new to this.

```js
<script>
    var aplicacion = angular.module('videos', [])
 
    
    aplicacion.controller('buscar',['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.videos = listaVideos
    }])
    aplicacion.controller('ordenar',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.videos = listaVideos
        $scope.filtro = 'Fecha';
        $scope.revertir = true;
        $scope.order = function(filtro) {
        $scope.revertir = ($scope.filtro === filtro) ? !$scope.revertir : false;
        $scope.filtro = filtro;
      };
    }])
                                  

    aplicacion.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.code = 'ZhetpzRXztc';

    });
  aplicacion.directive('myYoutube', function($sce) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { code:'=' },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log('here');
            scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
               if (newVal) {
                   scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
               }
            });
        }
      };
    });
    
    </script>
```

```css
.trianguloVideos:after {
  content: '\25b2'; }

/* line 393, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
.trianguloVideos.revertir:after {
  content: '\25bc'; }

/* line 396, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
.tablaVideos {
  margin-left: 20px;
  min-width: 920px; }
  /* line 400, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
  .tablaVideos tr td {
    padding: 10px; }
  /* line 406, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
  .tablaVideos tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background: #edecec; }
  /* line 409, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
  .tablaVideos th {
    min-width: 70px; }
    /* line 411, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
    .tablaVideos th a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #009dff; }
  /* line 417, C:/xampp/htdocs/meigacans/css/estilos.scss */
  .tablaVideos th:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <section>
            <h1>Videos</h1>
            <article ng-controller="buscar">
               <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
                  <div my-youtube code="code">
                      
                  </div>
                   
               </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="buscar">Buscar <input type="search" ng-model="buscar"></label>
                </div>
<table class="tablaVideos" ng-controller="ordenar" >
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a href="" ng-click="order('Nombre')">Nombre</a>
        <span class="trianguloVideos" ng-show="filtro === 'Nombre'" ng-class="{revertir:revertir}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a href="" ng-click="order('Fecha')">Fecha</a>
        <span class="trianguloVideos" ng-show="filtro === 'Fecha'" ng-class="{revertir:revertir}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a href="">Descripcion</a>
        <span class="trianguloVideos" ng-show="filtro === 'Descripcion'" ng-class="{revertir:revertir}"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="entrada in videos | orderBy:filtro:revertir | filter: buscar">
     <td><a ng-click="verVideos(entrada.Link)" href="">ver</a></td>
      <td class="Nombre">{{ entrada.Nombre }}</td>
      <td class="Fecha">{{ entrada.Fecha }}</td>
      <td>{{ entrada.Descripcion }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
            </article>
        </section>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how you're getting listaVideos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does scope.code exist with the proper value inside the directive link function? Use:

```
console.log(scope.code)
```

to see if the value is the one you want.

you probably missing the binding in the directive scope

```
scope: { code:'=code' }
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really scope.code if I put the code of the video for example "ZhetpzRXztc" plays smoothly, but I get link the ng-onclick to the video you have selected is played, do not know if I explained well, I miss the dynamic link between the ng-onclick for video data through the scope.code

Comment: I dont think you have to use $watch inside the link function, =code in the scope should do the work.